Not able to change theme by checkbox:checked
While trying to change the variable by checkbox:checked the variable is not getting changed for body element.
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="card.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body class="--flex-center"> <!-- The changes are not applied to <body> tag -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="inp-theme">
    <label for="inp-theme" class="checkbox"></label>
    <header>App Title</header>
    <!-- Other elements-->
</body>
</html>

CSS:
:root {
    --primary: black;
    --secondary: white;
}

body {
    background: var(--secondary);
}

header {
    color: var(--primary);
    background: var(--secondary);
}

.checkbox:checked ~ * {
    --primary: black;
    --secondary: white;
}

This works for all other elements but not for body. How I can change variable for body too. Using js is the last option, but can anyone help me with css. So according to code when checkbox checked the background and color of elements should be changed, but the background of <body> is not getting changed.

What is the --flex-center class? You didn't include that, please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

That don't affect question this comes from my regular css 'styles.css' which contain only display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;

The changed css custom property only works inside of its own context, not the parents context.


:root {
  --primary: black;
}

.outer,
.inner {
  background-color: var(--primary, black);
}

.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: var(--primary);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

p {
  padding: .5rem;
  color: #ddd
}

label {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.checkbox:checked ~ * {
  --primary: rebeccapurple;
}
<div class="outer">
  <p>this wont change</p>
  <div class="inner">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inp-theme" class="checkbox">
    <div class="foo">
      <p>this will change</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



If you want to change the css custom property globally, you have to use javascript document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary', 'lime');
EDIT:
As @a-haworth correctly said, you don't have to use javascript. You can manipulate the root css properties with :has.
:root {
  --primary: black;
}
:root:has(.checkbox:checked) {
  --primary: rebeccapurple;
}

EDIT 2:
I totally forgot that you can store css custom properties inside css custom properties. This makes it possible to change a css custom property value, as long as the value is also defined in the :root


:root {
  --color1: black;
  --color2: rebeccapurple;
  --primary: var(--color1);
}

.outer,
.inner {
  background-color: var(--primary);
}

.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: var(--primary);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

p {
  padding: .5rem;
  color: #ddd
}

label {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.checkbox:checked ~ * {
  --primary: var(--color2);
}
<div class="outer">
  <p>this wont change</p>
  <div class="inner">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inp-theme" class="checkbox">
    <div class="foo">
      <p>this will change</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



This way you could define your style guide inside the :root and only use the other css variables as values. You also do not have to use :has() for this.

It iis not true that you must use JS for this. THink about the :has CSS selection option.

You are right. I never used :has on :root but this also works: :root:has(input:checked) {    --primary: orangerod; }
